# Optimization: Return lowest value from array that is greater than (or equal to) `x`

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, optimization

EDIT: My question is different than the suggested duplicate because I already have a method of implementing `lowest`.  My question is not how to implement `lowest`, but rather how to optimize `lowest` to run faster.

Assume that I have an array `a`.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Assume that I have a float `x`.  For example:

```
x = 6.5
```

I want to return the lowest value in `a` that is also greater than or equal to `x`.  So in this case...

```
print lowest(a, x)
>>> 7
```

I have tried a number of function in place of `lowest`.  For example:

```
def lowest(a, x):
""" `a` should be a sorted numpy array"""
    return lowest[lowest >= x][0]

def lowest(a, x):
""" `a` should be a sorted `list`, not a numpy array"""
    k = sorted(a + [x])
    return k[k.index(x) + 1]
```

However, the function `lowest` remains the bottleneck of my code at ~90%.

**Is there a faster way to implement the function `lowest`?**

Some rules about my code:

- `a` can be assumed to have a length of 10
- the function `lowest` is run at least 100k times. This may be a design problem, but I am interested if there is a faster implementation of my problem first.
- `a` can be preprocessed before being run through these loops.  `x` will vary, but `a` will not.
- It can be assumed that `a[0] <= x <= a[-1]` is always `True`

Comment: Your first function uses invalid syntax. Your second one performs ridiculously inefficient operations. This should be an O(n) operation in time and O(1), or at most O(n) in space.

Comment: I just realized that `a` is sorted. In that case, it should be O(log n) in time and O(1) in space.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The array does not look sorted to me.

Comment: @miradulo: "`a` can be preprocessed before being run through these loops. `x` will vary, but `a` will not.". That's a direct quote.

Comment: `a[a >= x].min()`, or, if `a` is sorted, `a[a >= x][0]`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Right, my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an O(1) solution using lookup table compared to OP's (first) solution and `numpy.searchsorted`. It's not 100% fair because OP's solution is not vectorized. Anyway, timings:

```
True                  # results equal
True                  # results equal
0.08163515606429428   # lookup
2.1996873939642683    # OP
0.016975965932942927  # numpy.searchsorted
```

For this small list size `seachsorted` wins even though it is O(log n).

Code:

```
import numpy as np

class find_next:
    def __init__(self, a, max_bins=100000):
        self.a = np.sort(a)
        self.low = self.a[0]
        self.high = self.a[-1]
        self.span = self.a[-1] - self.a[0]
        self.damin = np.diff(self.a).min()
        if self.span // self.damin > max_bins:
            raise ValueError('a too unevenly spaced for max_bins')
        self.lut = np.searchsorted(self.a, np.linspace(self.low, self.high,
                                                       max_bins + 1))
        self.no_bins = max_bins
    def f_pp(self, x):
        i = np.array((x-self.low)/self.span * self.no_bins, int)
        return self.a[self.lut[i + (x > self.a[self.lut[i]])]]
    def lowest(self, x):
        return self.a[self.a >= x][0]
    def f_ss(self, x):
        return self.a[self.a.searchsorted(x)]

a = np.array([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

x = np.random.uniform(1, 9, (10000,))

fn = find_next(a)
sol_pp = fn.f_pp(x)
sol_OP = [fn.lowest(xi) for xi in x]
sol_ss = fn.f_ss(x)

print(np.all(sol_OP == sol_pp))
print(np.all(sol_OP == sol_ss))

from timeit import timeit
kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=10000)

print(timeit('fn.f_pp(x)', **kwds))
print(timeit('[fn.lowest(xi) for xi in x]', **kwds))
print(timeit('fn.f_ss(x)', **kwds))
```